# Changing the letter the keyboard types

Tags: windows, windows-vista, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I use windows vista. And I use Armenian keyword. So when I type for example "G" in Armenian it types an Armenian symbol. How I can configure to be able to type another Armenian symbol insted of the previews one while pushing "G" button?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator (MSKLC)](http://www.microsoft.com/globaldev/tools/msklc.mspx) may work for you.  This is an unsupported tool from Microsoft.

Good luck.